# What is the difference between using a parameter and just putting a variable then convert it

Tags: c#, asp.net, odbc

So I'm retrieving data from the database using odbc. One of my fields, which was causing the problem, is AutoNumber. In my query when I use, '" convert.toint64(empid)"', I get an error of data type missmatch. But when I used parameter, it worked perfectly. Can someone tell me what is the difference. As far as I know, AutoNumber is a long integer and long int is 64, right?

here are both of my queries:

```
        string cmdText = "SELECT p.projID, p.projName, a.wageperday " +
             "FROM ((projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname) " +
             "INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID= e.ID) " +
             "WHERE a.employeeID = ?";
        OdbcCommand assignslist = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, _connection);
        assignslist.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empID", empid);
        OdbcDataReader readassigns = assignslist.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = readassigns;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

(this one works fine)

```
        string cmdText = "SELECT p.projID, p.projName, a.wageperday " +
             "FROM ((projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname) " +
             "INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID= e.ID) " +
             "WHERE a.employeeID = '" + convert.toint64( empid ) + "';
        OdbcCommand assignslist = new OdbcCommand(cmdText, _connection);
        OdbcDataReader readassigns = assignslist.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = readassigns;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

for this one, i get an error even if I removed the conversion, I get an error.

One more question, I don't understand INNER JOIN perfectly and the above code was from a user here who helped me. I don't understand why did he use "FROM ((projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname) " +
                 "INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID= e.ID)"

two brackets -- I mean a bracket inside a bracket. And if I wanna join a 4th or 5th table do I have to put it inside a bracket aside from the main bracket? An example would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a.employeeID is a number then your problem are the quotes and the concatenation of a number to a string.

```
"WHERE a.employeeID = " + convert.toint64(empid).ToString()
```

but this make no sense because you have a string to build so, you could simply write

```
"WHERE a.employeeID = " + empid.ToString();
```

however use always the parameterized query. That is the correct way to go.

A parameterized query allows the Framework code to pass the parameters with the correct format and you don't have to worry about quoting values, format of dates and decimal separators. (And last but not least, you avoid any possibilities of Sql Injection)

For the second part of your question, [JOIN](http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is used to put togheter data from two tables, when you have more than one JOIN the parenthesys help to understand how the grouping from the tables are perfomed. First the data from `projects` and `assigns` are grouped together following the rules of the INNER JOIN then the resulting set of data is joined with the data from the `employee` table following the rules of the second join.

Comment: Thank you again Steve! Can you please help me understand INNER JOIN?

Comment: The link in the answer should be a good starting point to study JOINs

Answer (score 1):

In your second query, instead of using `convert.toint64( empid )` try using `empid.ToString()`:

```
"WHERE a.employeeID = " + empid.ToString();
```

The error you were receiving was due to the fact that you were trying to concatenate a string with an integer.

With regards to the `INNER JOIN`s you are using, the use of the brackets is dependant upon the database you are using.  In most cases, you will not need the brackets at all and they can be removed without any issue, so you could rewrite the query to:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT p.projID, p.projName, a.wageperday " +
    "FROM projects p " +
    "INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname " +
    "INNER JOIN empos e ON a.employeeID = e.ID " +
    "WHERE a.employeeID = " empid.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a string and an integer, which isn't allowed automatically.  You'd have to convert the number to a string first, like this:

```
"WHERE a.employeeID = '" + empid.ToString() + "';
```

But, using parameters is the better way for other reasons (best habit to be in, to avoid SQL-injection attacks, etc.).